# Colorbox not working for anonymous users, but works fine for logged in

Tags: 7, media, javascript

I am having an issue getting my colorboxed images to load while viewing the page as an anonymous user. As an anonymous user, there is no reference to anything related to colorbox at all. However, when logged in as admin, everything works fine.

This feels like a permissions issue, but I don't see any settings in permissions. also, the configuration in the 'manage display' settings leave a bit to the imagination.

What am I doing wrong? Is this indeed a permissions issue? 7.x 1.3 and drupal 7.14

Comment: Can you post a link?

Comment: http://tourismbuilder1.hokkaido-select.com/content/dart-bar-que-sera-sera voila! Each of those three should be a link that, when clicked, open in a Colorbox. Again, works fine when logged in. Thanks!

Comment: http://tourismbuilder1.hokkaido-select.com/content/traditional-mochi-making here it seems to work .. just do the same ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a javascript conflict in my theme. Works great now that that has been cleared up. Thanks!